# Animate specific paragraph using wow.js onclick

Tags: jquery, wow.js

I am using wow.js to animate different elements on the page when scrolling.
Now I want to rise the animation only on the specific paragraph when clicked on the button (in jQuery).

```
<p id="reasons" class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">x y z</p>
```

I don't want to initialize the page with the animation once again (see below), but only animate this concrete paragraph (with `id = "reasons"`).

```
new WOW().init();
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="mybutton">button</button>

<p id="reasons" data-wow-delay="0.2s">x y z</p>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
    $("#reasons").addClass("wow fadeInUp animated");
    $("#reasons").attr("style","visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;");
});
```

On bootstrap tabs it also works. :-)

Comment: Thanks!  This worked perfectly for me.  I used it to hide and then fade in different bootstrap panels based on clicking different tabs.

Answer (score 1):

WOW.js works with page scroll.

You can trigger the animation using jQuery `toggleClass()` Method on click.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reasons").click(function() {
      $(".box").toggleClass("animated");
    });
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.6/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="reasons" class="box infinite fadeInUp">Click to animate</p>
```

*I have added an extra `infinite` class so that the change is more visible.*

Make sure you have linked to `animate.css` in your page.
Clicking on the paragraph changes the `box` class to `animated` class which is necessary for the animation.

**Source:**

[Triggering CSS3 Transitions With JavaScript](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-transitions-javascript/)

[Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: Thanks you Ashesh.
Finally I resolved it calling: 
`$("#reasons").fadeOut(); $("#reasons").fadeIn();` 
and the animation onclick seems to be the same as wow.js does.